# How to check number of values missing per observation?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I have the following function to check number of missing values for different columns:

```
shape = df.shape
df_miss = df.isnull().sum()
x = df_miss.index
y = df_miss
z = []
for i in x:
    if y[i] > 0:
        z.append(i)
print(z)
plt.bar(z,y[z])
```

Now I would like to use the same function to find the cases/observations with missing values.

Comment: post the sample dataframe and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `axis` argument to apply `sum` on rows instead of columns:

```py
df_miss = df.isna().sum(axis=1)
x = df_miss.index
z = df_miss[df_miss > 0].index
```

Answer (score 1):

For a record you can use
`df['featurename']`
in which you want to find the missing values
or
`df[['1','2']]`
to get the missing values using the isnull()
and provide the axis=1.i.e along the columns